# Ubuntu 22.04 how to get wifi adapter into radio test mode (for emc regulation tests)

Tags: drivers, wireless, iwlwifi, certification

Is there a way to get the wifi adapter in my pc to go into radio test mode. This mode is usually used when approving a wifi adapter/module for EMC regulations. This test allows for constant transmission, adjusting duty cycle, changing wifi channels etc..

Current adapter in my PC is Intel® Wi-Fi 6E AX211. I contacted intel support and they stated that the OS would be able to put the wifi adapter into test mode

Wondering if any one has done this to go through emc testing?